# python mkdir to make folder with subfolder?

Tags: python, operating-system, directory, mkdir

This works:

```
mkdir('folder')
```

but this doesn't

```
mkdir('folder/subfolder')
```

error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'folder/subfolder'
```

Comment: did you try `mkdir('folder\subfolder')`?

Answer (score 134):

Try [`os.makedirs`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.makedirs) instead, if you want to create a tree of directories in one call.

Comment: just like in java

Comment: Ahhh `makedirs()`... not `mkdirs()`... of course. Why would it be `mkdirs()`? That would be silly. I would like those 7 minutes back.

Answer (score 40):

I tried the above on Linux using Python 2.6.6, but had to ensure that the string ended with a '/' (or '\', on Windows). E.g.

```
os.makedirs('folder/subfolder/')
```

Otherwise only 'folder' was created.

Comment: `os.makedirs(os.path.join("folder", "subfolder"))` should work

Answer (score 24):

I think you want the [os.makedirs()](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/os.html#os.makedirs) function, which can create intermediate directories.